# Populating an embedded UITableViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uitableview, segue

I have an app using a navigation controller. In one of the views, I have a view container with an embedded UITableViewController using static cells. I need to populate this table view controller's labels with data passed in from a previous view. The flow is as follows

View1 > segue-> Parent>Child

I need to pass data from View1 to Child. When testing this, it appears that Child's viewDidLoad fires BEFORE Parent's viewDidLoad. This doesn't seem logical to me. Using viewDidAppear on the Child works, but there is latency in updating the labels, which isn't really acceptable.

Can anyone shed light on how to update an embedded UITableViewController when its parent is loaded?

Thanks!

Comment: How are you passing the data to the child?

Comment: Data is passed to the parent via a segue. My thoughts were to update the child with this data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the data to the parent in prepareForSegue, and in viewDidLoad (of the parent) pass the string to the child. In the child, set the value of its label with this string in viewWillAppear:.