# how to access tableviewcontroller embedded inside a container view

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicontainerview

I have a custom UIViewController "ProfileController" with 2 child subviews - the most important being a container child subview which embeds a UITableViewController. How do I access the UITableViewController from within the "ProfileController" so I can dynamically configure the "static" cells that I am using to show user profile information.

I didn't want to use a standalone UITableViewController as then I can't add additional customizations to the UI for the profile screen. Thanks!

...it's unfortunate I can't design static cells for the standard UITableView within a storyboard as I found out Apples implementation of static cells is tightly coupled to UITableViewController. Bummer, indeed.

Comment: What does say `[self childViewControllers]`?

Comment: @Larme Yes, I do see the UITableVIewController as a child view controller. Is there a way I can add outlets from the embedded child view controller back to the ProfileController source file so I can dynamically configure the cell contents? Or do I have to subclass the nested uitableviewcontroller. Thanks.

Comment: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20176561/populating-an-embedded-uitableviewcontroller solved how to pass data from parent-to-child. I had to use viewWillAppear to read back data from parent.

Answer (score 2):

In your `ProfileController` override:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!){
    if segue.identifier == "whateverYouNamedTheEmbedSegue"{
        myTableViewController = segue.destinationViewController as UITableViewController
    }
}
```